# Replace all domain including subdomain name using PHP with Regex

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I am using `preg_replace` or `str_replace` in PHP to replace all the domain name including `www`

```
$string = ' https://example.com, https://www.example.com, https://subdomain.example.com ';
$olddomain= "example.com";
$newdomain = "stackoverflow.com";

$output = str_replace($olddomain, $newdomain, $string);
$output = preg_replace('#(www[.])?[.]' . $olddomain. '#', $newdomain, $body);

echo $output;
```

**My expectation:**

```
https://example.com -> https://stackoverflow.com

https://www.example.com -> https://stackoverflow.com

https://subdomain.example.com -> https://subdomain.example.com
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a regex, just pass the `www.` with the other change in into `str_replace()`. Remember `str_replace()` accepts an array of things to "change from" and "change to".

```
$string = ' https://example.com, https://www.example.com, https://subdomain.example.com ';
$olddomain = ["example.com",'www.'];
$newdomain = ["stackoverflow.com", ''];

$output = str_replace($olddomain, $newdomain, $string);
echo $output;
```

RESULT

```
 https://stackoverflow.com, https://stackoverflow.com, https://subdomain.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com.stackoverflow.com` have you noticed this error. it should be `https://stackoverflow.com` not `https://stackoverflow.com.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: FIxed it already, sorry someone asked me a question and I got distracted

Comment: No problem. yes, it working. But how it working. `["example.com",'www.'];` means it will try to match in both combination?

Comment: No, it does the changes one occurance at a time So look for `$olddomain[0]` if found change to  `$newdomain[0]` etc etc

Comment: So, it work as `for loop` with `PHP Array`

Answer (score 2):

preg_replace with regex.

```
$string = ' https://example.com, https://www.example.com, https://subdomain.example.com ';
$olddomain= "example.com";
$newdomain = "stackoverflow.com";

$output = preg_replace('#(https://(www\.)?)' . $olddomain. '#', '$1' . $newdomain, $string);

echo $output;
```

**Output :**

```
https://stackoverflow.com, https://www.stackoverflow.com, https://subdomain.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using `Regex`

```
$string = ' https://example.com, https://www.example.com, https://subdomain.example.com ';
$olddomain= "example.com";
$newdomain = "stackoverflow.com";

$parts = explode(",", $string);
$new_parts = [];

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $new_parts[] = str_replace(['https://', 'http://', $olddomain], ['https://', 'http://', $newdomain], $part);
}

$output = implode(",", $new_parts);

echo $output;
```

Return

```
https://stackoverflow.com, https://www.stackoverflow.com, https://subdomain.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

With Array and Regex

```
$string = ' https://example.com, https://www.example.com, https://subdomain.example.com ';
$olddomain = ["example.com", 'www\.'];
$newdomain = ["stackoverflow.com", ''];

$output = preg_replace('#https://(' . implode('|', $olddomain) . ')#', 'https://' . $newdomain[0], $string);
$output = preg_replace('#(' . $olddomain[1] . ')#', $newdomain[1], $output);

echo $output;
```