# How to exclude image extension from string place in PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I want to replace all the string values from `example.com` to `sample.com` excluding the image extension `.png`, `.jpeg`, `.jpg` etc.

```
$body = ' www.example.com, example.com, example.com/hello.html, example.com/logo.png, example.com/yourbaby.php , example.com/newimage.jpg, www.example.com/newimage.jpg';

//values    
$oldomain = ['example.com','www.']; 
$newdomain= ['sample.com', ''];
$excludeextension = [".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"];

//Replace    
$body = str_replace($olddomain, $newdomain, $body);
$body = str_replace($excludeextension, '', $body);

//output    
 echo $body;
```

**Output i am looking for :**

```
sample.com, sample.com, sample.com/hello.html, example.com/logo.png, sample.com/yourbaby.php , example.com/newimage.jpg, www.example.com/newimage.jpg
```

**Expectation**

```
https://example.com -> https://sample.com

https://www.example.com -> https://sample.com

https://subdomain.example.com -> https://subdomain.sample.com

https://www.example.com/image.png -> https://www.example.com/image.png

https://example.com/image.png -> https://example.com/image.png
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck? We're happy to help if necessary but it's not a free outsourcing service. Please read [ask]

Comment: Good code indentation and layout would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry for my misunderstanding while writing question. I have updated everything with clear.

Comment: @MehulKumar No need, I think the misunderstanding was all mine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `str_replace()` and a bit of exploding and imploding.

```
$body = ' www.example.com, example.com, example.com/hello.html, example.com/logo.png, example.com/yourbaby.php, example.com/newimage.jpg, www.example.com/newimage.jpg';

$oldomain = ['example.com','www.']; 
$newdomain= ['sample.com', ''];
$excludeextension = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg"];

$doms = explode(',', $body);
foreach ($doms as &$dom) {
    // get extension
    $pi = pathinfo($dom);
    if ( ! in_array( $pi['extension'], $excludeextension) ){
        $dom = str_replace($oldomain, $newdomain, $dom);
    }

}
$NewStr = implode($doms);
echo $NewStr;
```

RESULT

```
sample.com sample.com sample.com/hello.html example.com/logo.png sample.com/yourbaby.php example.com/newimage.jpg www.example.com/newimage.jpg
```

Comment: I have updated my question. I am using array as you mentioned yesterday here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75311164/20776947 . I have tried this answer with your yesterday answer and it giving an error. `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$excludeextension' (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: There is no mistake in your code. But like yesterday i said `www.example.com` or `example.com` should be changed to `sample.com`. So you given me a solution to use `PHP Array`. So, when i am using with array like `$oldomain = ['example.com','www.'];` and `$newdomain= ['sample.com', '']` than i am getting an error. **I have also updated my question**

Comment: I am trying to merge your `this answer` and your this answer `https://stackoverflow.com/a/75311164/20776947` and the result is (**error**) : https://3v4l.org/qpOeU

Comment: Yes this working great as expected. So, i can add multiple extension like `css`, `js`, etc. Thanks again.

Comment: I think so, but give it a try

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` & `str_replace`
2. First `explode` than `implode`

`$body = 'example.com, www.example.com, https://www.example.com, https://example.com, subdomain.example.com, example.com/logo.png, www.example.com/logo.png, example.com/hello/logo.png, https://example.com/logo.png, subdomain.example.com/logo.png"';`

```
//Defined Values 
$oldomain = ["example.com", "www.example.com"];
$newdomain = "sample.com";
$excludeextension = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "css"];

// Split the string into an array of URLs
$urls_body_extension = explode(", ", $body);

// Loop through each URL and replace it if necessary
foreach ($urls_body_extension as &$url_body_extension) {
    $extension_body_extension = pathinfo($url_body_extension, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (!in_array($extension_body_extension, $excludeextension)) {
        foreach ($oldomain as $domain_body_extension) {
            if (strpos($url_body_extension, $domain_body_extension) !== false) {
                $url_body_extension = str_replace($domain_body_extension, $newdomain, $url_body_extension);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Join the modified URLs back into a string
$body = implode(", ", $urls_body_extension);

echo $body;
```